# Python: Center plot and legend on sheet with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, centering

I have a polar plot and to the right of it its legend. The legend can have between 1 and 40 items whose length will be between 4 and 32 characters. My goal is to center the plot and the legend as if it was one object on the matplotlib "sheet" (or rather empty whitespace).

I found the following and adjusted it to my needs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

for ap in aps:
    ax.plot(angles, ap, label="----------32-Characters---------")

# Shrink current axis by 20%
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])

# Put a legend to the right of the current axis
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

plt.show()
```

The problem is it doesn't adjust for the length of the labels. Everything perfectly fits when the labels are 4-8 characters long but as it does just shrink the plot by 20 % as soon as 32 character long string appear, they are cut off!

**What I want** is the plot + legend as one object centered on the sheet/page/empty whitespace, so that when there is a long label the plot is just offset a little bit more to the left in order to compensate for it.
I hope you got my point of what I am trying to do :)

Comment: I think you may find what you need in the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014609/matplotlib-legend-height-in-pixels) question - you'll have to draw the figure then get the legend size then re-adjust if it's too wide.